# How to setState() from within a nested function in React?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to adapt this example from https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/tree/master/basic,

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA';

class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lng: 5,
      lat: 34,
      zoom: 1.5
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom
    });

    map.on('move', () => {
      const { lng, lat } = map.getCenter();

      this.setState({
        lng: lng.toFixed(4),
        lat: lat.toFixed(4),
        zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2)
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="inline-block absolute top left mt12 ml12 bg-darken75 color-white z1 py6 px12 round-full txt-s txt-bold">
          <div>{`Longitude: ${lng} Latitude: ${lat} Zoom: ${zoom}`}</div>
        </div>
        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} className="absolute top right left bottom" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

to a case in which, rather than displaying the map's center, I would like to display the latitude and longitude of the mouse position.

So far, I've managed to simply log it to the console:

```
import React from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3VydHBlZWsiLCJhIjoiY2p6cnVneWdvMHlzeDNqcWo0dm83ZzZ2eiJ9.yUCSreTRcKs12uT5PTCztg';


export default class Map extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
      center: [-119.5591, 37.715],
      zoom: 9
    });

    this.map.on('load', function(e) {    
      e.target.on('mousemove', function(e) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e.point));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap()));
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.map.remove();
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      width: '100%'
    };

    return <div style={style} ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} />;
  }
}
```

This writes lines like the following to the console:

```
{"x":972,"y":272}
{"lng":-118.90266689452113,"lat":37.86205552587528}
```

However, rather than logging the coordinates to the console, I would like to invoke `this.setState()` like in the example so that I can render the coordinates in a child component.

The problem is, within the `on('mousemove', ...)` callback function, `this` is not the component. I've read about using arrow functions (which are lexically scoped) to work around this, but it seems to me that in this case, I need a 'normal' `function(e)` in order to capture the event.

How can I `setState()` with the mouse coordinates in this example?

Comment: I don't think you need normal functions to capture the event...

Comment: You can use this `(e) => { ... }`.

Comment: You could do `his.map.on('load', (function(e) {  ... }).bind(this)` or `const me=this;his.map.on('load', function(e) { me.setState... } ` or use an arrow function instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use `arrow functions` just like any other `function`

```
this.map.on('load', e => {    
  e.target.on('mousemove', e => {
      this.setState({}) //correct this
  })
})
```

Comment: This works great; in the `on('load', ...)` callback, I was also able to consistently use `this.map` rather than `e.target`.

Comment: Great! Lexical `this` is realy helpful in situations like this